# Create a slider menu in pure CSS with a Trigger Button

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a slider menu in pure CSS. It cannot have any JS or any other framework. I have been able to create one, but the button pressed to open the menu cannot be moved. I have created one as below:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
p,
li {
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

section li {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 80px;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -250px;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

nav ul {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: #111;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #1ea1b8;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  z-index: 500;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~nav {
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label {
  left: 260px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~section {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(260px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(260px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(260px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(260px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="navigation" />
<label for="navigation">
        +
    </label>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Latest News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">What We Do</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Another Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This works, however - when I try to move the TRIGGER button to another location, for example, inside a DIV container, the menu doesn't work anymore, for example;

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Latest News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">What We Do</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Another Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="navigation" />
  <label for="navigation">
    +
  </label>
</div>
```

I am trying to incorporate this slider menu into a CMS system, and I want to place the 'open menu' button in a specific place on the page. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you put this together in a snippet so we can see it (not quite) working?

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ nav` no longer applies because you changed the structure of your html. With your current label in div structure, this cannot be achieved with css alone. You need to be able to relate your label with the nav element

Comment: @DBS  - https://codepen.io/marclloyd77/pen/gtypB

Comment: As long as your `<label>` keeps referencing the checkbox with `for`, it'll stay linked to it, so you can move your `<input type="checkbox" id="navigation" />` to be the first child of `<body>` and change your CSS to target higher level ancestors, so `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ * nav`, for example. Anyone reading, keep in mind this is terrible practice for accessibility.